# How to detect if Twitter API home timeline limit has been reached?

Tags: rest, api, twitter, pagination

Twitter limits the number of obtainable tweets on the home timeline to 800. After cursoring through the responses until there are no more pages to collect all available tweets, I want to detect if I have reached this limit or not.

I cannot think of a reliable heuristic for doing so. Sadly it is not as simple as checking if the length of retrieved tweets equals the limit, because—if I understand correctly—suspended or deleted content is removed after the limit is put into force. For example, we may have 600 tweets instead of 800 because 200 were suspended/deleted, but we could also have the same amount because we didn't reach the limit.

Answer (score 0):

For all requests after the first page, set `max_id` parameter to the id of oldest tweet received in previous page (or one less than this). Stop when id of oldest tweet in present response is same as the `max_id` you sent (or if response is empty).

See: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/timelines

Comment: Hi @pii_ke, I am indeed doing this, however "does last response contain one tweet" is not a heuristic for whether we've hit the limit, as this will *also* match cases where the timeline actually contains less tweets than the limit, in which case the last response would still contain one tweet.

Comment: Well, you are correct. This method tells when to stop asking for older tweets. It does not tell whether the timeline has no more tweets or the limit is reached. Are you interested detecting this difference?

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to tell the difference between those two scenarios: timeline exhausted or limit reached.

Comment: Well. There are some things I might have tried. One is to compare the `timestamp` of oldest tweet with the twitter user's `created_at` timestamp. The other is to maintain a `oldest_known_tweet_timestamp` field in the local twitter user database, updating it whenever I find some tweet older than that. Also try to somehow retrieve any older tweet using `/search/tweets`endpoint of REST API or by scraping Twitter's advanced search interface on website. Finally I would have inspected HTTP headers returned with Twitter response. They may have debug info useful for this.